# Get widget name of label in frame using mouse

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, label, frame

Win7 SP1, Python 2.7,Tkinter.

I make a frame, and I place an array of labels within. The array is 10w x 24h.

I want to click on one of these labels and return the name of the label so I may alter it's variable.

I know how to do using a listbox, but how to do using just 'label in a frame'?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the label name, and besides labels don't have useful names. When the event fires you are given a reference to the widget, which you can use to query or modify the widget attributes.

Here's an example of how you can change a label by clicking on it. Run the program, and then click on any label as often as you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

def on_click(event):
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    event.widget.configure(text="you clicked me at %s" % now)

root = tk.Tk()
for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        label = tk.Label(root, width=25, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=2, pady=2)
        label.bind("<1>", on_click)

root.mainloop()
```